# Apache redirect to Tomcat app with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, spring-security

I have a java app that is served up by Tomcat (ie. http://111.222.333.444:8080/myApp). My client wants this app to respond to a friendly domain (ie. http://client.example.com). I'm not very good with Apache or Tomcat, but I configured Apache like this to do the redirect:

```
<VirtualHost 111.222.333.444:80>
    ServerName client.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://111.222.333.444:8080/myApp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://111.222.333.444:8080/myApp/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 111.222.333.444 client.example.com

    ProxyPass /login.html http://111.222.333.444:8080/login.html
    ProxyPassReverse /login.html http://111.222.333.444:8080/login.html
</VirtualHost>
```

This works great to serve up the app under http://client.example.com. However, I have a login page implemented using Spring Security. The login works fine when accessing it from http://111.222.333.444:8080/myApp/login.html. However, when I access it from http://client.example.com/login.html and enter a valid username and password, it just loads the login page again with no errors.

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter looks like this. I couldn't get it to even load the login page correctly without passing the absolute URL to loginPage().

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("http://client.example.com/login.html")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

My login page looks like this:

```
<form name="f" method="post" action="/login.html">               
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please Login</legend>           
        <label for="username">User</label>
        <select id="username" name="username">
            <option value="-1"></option>
            <option value="admin">admin</option>
        </select>           
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" role="button"><span>Login</span></button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

So when I visit http://client.example.com/admin/test.html, I am correctly redirected to http://client.example.com/login.html. But when I try to login with "admin"/"admin", it just loads the login page again at http://client.example.com/login.html without any errors. The apache logs, tomcat logs, and application logs don't tell me anything helpful.

I think it's related to the Apache proxy not playing nicely with Spring Security, since it works when hitting the Tomcat app directly, but I'm not sure.

1. How can I get Apache/Spring Security to handle the login correctly? I would expect the app to recognize that I'm logged in and direct me to the admin page I was trying to access.
2. Is there a way to get the login page to work without using the absolute URL in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Apache version:  Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
Spring Security version: 3.2.6.RELEASE
Tomcat version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Java version: Java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I think your login form action should not be pointing to your login page URL, but rather

```
/j_spring_security_check
```

The UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is looking for that to imitate the authentication process. If you don't want to use /j_spring_security_check, you can tell the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to look for another URL by setting the calling the loginProcessingUrl method on your FormLoginConfigurer like this:

```
formlogin()
    .loginProcessingUrl('/custom_login_url')
    .loginPage("http://client.domain.com/login.html")
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I had actually tried that before with no luck. When I change the form action to be /j_spring_security_check, the form posts to htt p://client.domain.com/j_spring_security_check and I get a "405 Method Not Allowed". I also tried changing the fields to j_username and j_password because that's what it looks like UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is looking for, but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you have the csrf disabled at the time you had the form post action set to "/j_spring_security_check" ?

Comment: Yes, it was disabled. I have since tried enabling it, which successfully sends the csrf token in the POST, but then I get a "403 Forbidden".Do I need to have https configured in order to use spring security correctly?